# Replace a dynamic object with T

Tags: c#, oop, dynamic

We have a struct which contains dynamic data provided by one source and errors in a fixed format like so:

```
struct AllOurInfo {
    public dynamic TheData {get;set;}
    public string[] Errors {get;set;}
}
```

TheData can be various things. A single string or a collection of various types.

The data cannot be structured sometimes (in which case it should remain dynamic, or it can be structured in which case it should be a struct.

**How would you go about turning TheData into a non-dynamic object?**

I'm looking for something along the lines of this (if that's even possible)

```
AllOurInfo.TheData = EvaluateData(dData);
public ParentDataClass EvaluateData(dynamic dData)
{
    // Figure out the type of data, call the right class
    return new ChildDataClass()
}

struct AllOurInfo<T> {
    public T TheData {get;set;}  // or whatever class T is rather
    public string[] Errors {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: And what is purpose of generics if you don't know the type at compile-time?!

Comment: Normally we should. I just added that part to understand how it works better. I can think of situations where it's useful but yeah it's certainly not optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics are best used when you know at compile-time the types you want to use. You *could* use generics if you wanted to deal with this:

1. Have a base `AllOurInfo` class with only the `Errors` property, you would be returning this.
2. Have a `AllOurInfo<T> : AllOurInfo` class.
3. After determining the type of `T` in `EvaluateData`, use Reflection to create an instance of `AllOurInfo<T>` with the determined `T`, and return that as `AllOurInfo`
4. Cast the returned value wherever you are using it from `AllOurInfo` back to `AllOurInfo<T>`.

Overall, you wouldn't be winning too much, and you wouldn't be able to do this if you cannot use Reflection.

I see two options here:

1. If you have too many different types of `T`, leave it as-is.
2. If you have only a few, you could use a Factory approach:

```
public interface IAllOurInfo
{
    string[] Errors { get; }
}
public interface IAllOurInfo<T> : IAllOurInfo
{
    T TheData { get; }
}
public struct AllOurStringInfo : IAllOurInfo<string>
{
    public string[] Errors { get; private set; }
    public string TheData { get; private set; }

    public AllOurStringInfo(string[] errors, string theData)  : this()
    {
        Errors = errors;
        TheData = theData;
    }
}

public struct AllOurStringArrayInfo : IAllOurInfo<string[]>
{
    public string[] Errors { get; private set; }
    public string[] TheData { get; private set; }

    public AllOurStringArrayInfo(string[] errors, string[] theData) : this()
    {
        Errors = errors;
        TheData = theData;
    }
}

public IAllOurInfo EvaluateData(dynamic dData)
{
    // Figure out the type of data, call the right class

    // I am just giving an example here 
    if (dData.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
        return new AllOurStringInfo(new[] { "Hello" }, "Hello");
    }

    // have no idea what I was given, return null or throw
    return null;
}
```

Of course, you would still need to cast to the type expected.

Comment: That cleared up a lot of things, thanks! In my scenario it would be 5-10 types that would be used in various places in the app. The point would be to efficiently call these without risking typos or having to convert the object multiple times (newtonsoft json deserialized object). And I'm guessing dynamic objects use more resources as well to call (?)
It's probably overkill in my situation but it's useful to have a better understanding of this in any case.

Comment: @user550385 Serializing would be extremely worse than casting from an interface to the expected type. I would much rather you just casted than lose several seconds serializing.

Comment: That's where I was going before I got an answer tbh :P But I'm still glad I got it. A lot of new concepts for me to learn in this answer.